# Windows 10 code block font size

Tags: windows, windows-10, css, dpi

Basically, all the code blocks have super small fonts. Example from JSFiddle below.

This applies seemingly everywhere.

It's sized to 11.9px according to developer tools. Windows 10 64 bit.

**Edit:** It's not just Chrome, it's every browser

[image: Example]

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? Is DPI scaling enabled? Can you inspect a code block (right click -> inspect), switch to *Computed* tab and check `font-size` and `font-family`?

Comment: @gronostaj Font size is 11.9px like I said. Extensions and profile are fine (incognito with no extensions gives same result) and DPI scaling is off. Don't see how DPI scaling would matter here since it's just code blocks though.

Comment: Please check `font-family` property too.

Comment: Do you have KB3013455  & KB3037639  installed ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like any way to check?

Comment: @Ieuan, I was reading in google forums that one of these windows update was causing the issue and other was fixing it. Which windows are you using ? Search for **view installed updates** if you are on windows 7

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like like I said in my question; Windows 10 64 bit. Found installed update list but it gives no result for either of those updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the text being rendered by certain `pre` tags as Monaco. Apparently Monaco is a broken font that does not at all scale well, causing the 10-12px text to be impossible to read.

**I removed Monaco Default from my `C:\Windows\Fonts` and now it is all rendered in the first fallback font in line, which renders fine**